# How can I position my header in the middle of my nav?

Tags: html, css, position

How can I set up the positioning of my nav and header to look like this?

[image]

I have been trying search around on google and stack overflow, but couldn't find anything.

Here is my code, thanks.

```css
body
{
background-image: url('bground.png');
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
}

#wrap { margin: 0 auto; width: 700px; }

#header{

}


ul, li, a{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
font-family: arial;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
}

li, a:hover{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 25px;
color: #ffdc99;
}

#content{
background: #ffffff;
max-width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* Edits */
#header,
#content{ clear: both; }

#header,
#header h1,
#header #nav { float: left; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Gullible</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">

    <div id="logo">
        <h1>Gullible</h1>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="home.html">Visit</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

</div>

  <footer>
  <h2>Gullible</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li>Visit</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Flexbox** and [`justify-content: space-around;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

> Flex items are evenly distributed so that the space between two adjacent items is the same. The empty space before the first and after the last items equals half of the space between two adjacent items.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">LINK</a></li>
  <li><a href="">LINK</a></li>
  <li class="logo"><a href="">LOGO</a></li>
  <li><a href="">LINK</a></li>
  <li><a href="">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place your `<h1>` inside of a new `<li>` in the center of the existing ones.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <li><h1>Gullible</h1></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Visit</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find an example of how you can achieve that https://jsfiddle.net/5czgjkyj/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="logo">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><h1>Gullible</h1></li>
        <li><a href="home.html">Visit</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li><h2>Gullible</h2></li>
      <li>Visit</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>
```

css

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```